# MYSQL 8 + : Query to find the products under categories , when category is in hierarchy and product is attached to leaf category node

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database, common-table-expression

Table : categories

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronics | null |
| 2 | TV | 1 |
| 3 | Portable | 1 |
| 4 | CRT | 2 |
| 5 | LCD | 2 |
| 6 | Plasma | 2 |
| 7 | Mp3 Players | 3 |
| 8 | CD Players | 3 |
| 9 | Flash | 7 |

Table : products (products are attached to the leaf category id)

| id | name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flash Player | 9 |
| 2 | Samsung LCD TV | 5 |
| 3 | LG Plasma TV | 6 |

Query to generate the category_products results set ??

Results set :

| id | product_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (Flash Player) | 9 (Flash) |
| 2 | 1 (Flash Player) | 7 (Mp3 Players) |
| 3 | 1 (Flash Player) | 3 (Portable) |
| 4 | 1 (Flash Player) | 1 (Electronics) |
| 5 | 2 (Samsung LCD TV) | 5 (LCD) |
| 6 | 2 (Samsung LCD TV) | 2 (TV) |
| 7 | 2(Samsung LCD TV) | 1 (Electronics) |
| 5 | 3 (LG Plasma TV) | 5 (PLasma) |
| 6 | 3 (LG Plasma TV) | 2 (TV) |
| 7 | 3(LG Plasma TV) | 1 (Electronics) |

How can we generate this results set from mysql query ?

Comment: Interesting question! Can you create the table schema or a fiddle so that its easy to recreate the dataset and work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  recursive_membership AS
(
  SELECT
    p.id     AS product_id,
    p.name   AS product_name,
    c.id     AS category_id,
    c.name   AS category_name,
    c.parent AS category_parent_id
  FROM
    products     p
  INNER JOIN
    categories   c
      ON c.id = p.category_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    r.product_id,
    r.product_name,
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.parent
  FROM
    recursive_membership   r
  INNER JOIN
    categories             c
      ON c.id = r.category_parent_id
)
SELECT
  product_id,
  product_name,
  category_id,
  category_name
FROM
  recursive_membership
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MatBailie . Can we optimize the query little more?

Comment: @ShramikNakarmi - That totally depends on the indexes you have on the table, how you're using the query in practice, how much data you have in the tables, etc, etc.  I suggest you open a new question with a specific focus on optimising a use case, and include the EXPLAIN plan, table definitions (including all indexes), etc, etc.